# Foursquare api request returns error code 200 sometimes

Tags: ios, iphone, foursquare

I am using the following code to request the Foursquare *venues/explore* endpoint for nearby locations:

```
NSString *key = searchBox.text ? [searchBox.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"] : @"";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMdd"];
NSString* date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

[dateFormatter release];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=%f,%f&query=%@&radius=50000&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=%@", myMapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, myMapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude, key, date];
```

Most of the times, it returns results as expected, but other times, it returns the **error code 200**. From the [docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning) I can see it means that I am using a deprecated value. I do not understand, if the `date` I am passing is causing the problems. I tried to find out if it needs a specific version, or the current date. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The date you pass in to the `v` param should be a fixed date greater than `20120609`. This is the "version" of the API response you want and your application is capable of parsing. It's a little unexpected that the 200 deprecated only sometimes comes back—it should always come back if you're passing in a `v` param less than `20120609`.

Foursquare occasionally changes the JSON format of its responses and the `v` param is a tool for you to safeguard against these changes. (To see an example, make a request with `20110101` and `20140101` and notice the change in structure). You should periodically update this fixed date and check to see if anything has broken. For more information, see [the docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning).

Comment: Yes, but since i'm using `dateFormatter` and passing the absolute current date using `[NSDate date]`, the response object structure should be the latest, should it not ? Why a deprecated message?

Comment: Because you shouldn't pass the current date. If Foursquare published a JSON format on 20120609 and your code was written to parse and understand that JSON format, then you should pass 20120609. You are basically saying "I can parse and understand the format that you published today", and Foursquare says "well, we didn't publish any JSON format today, so what you say is wrong".

Comment: The API shouldn't return a deprecated warning if you're using a version > 20120609. I'm not too familiar with dateFormatter, but it looks like it should cover the case of single-digit months... but just to double check, make sure you're not passing in a string like `2014328` instead of `20140328`

Comment: This might just be the silliest thing I have ever done, courtesy my lethargy. Till now, I was only logging the error code, and not the description. The error was due to the `"There aren't a lot of results near you..."` warning. The endpoint works exactly as it should. I apologise.